# Chrome Developer Tools - JavaScript inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypejs, prototype, google-chrome-devtools

Can I see JavaScript inheritance in Chrome Dev Tools? Is there any visualization etc?

[image]

e.g.

```
if(typeof Object.create !== 'function') {
    Object.create = function (o) {
        function F() {}  
        F.prototype = o; 
        return new F();  
    };
}
var superInstance = {
    member1: 'superMember1',
    member2: 'superMember2'
};
var subInstance = Object.create(superInstance);
subInstance.member3 = 'subMember3';
```

Answer (score 2):

There might be extensions that parse all JS-files and are able to come up with such a visualization (though I doubt that). But I'm pretty sure Chrome Developer Tools does **not** have this built-in.

Comment: I'd argue that since JavaScript doesn't really have Classes, SubClasses and thus true inheritance that getting debugging info on something that doesn't exist will be unlikely.

Comment: Hence my 'though I doubt that'. I'd figure that, to create such a visualization, you need check all methods and properties of all objects and **predict** an inheritance pattern. There is definitely no 'real inheritance' in JS.